# Rails 4.2: updating relationships, via a relationship…

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-many, has-one, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a the following models:

```
class Part
  belongs_to :note, inverse_of: :part, dependent: :destroy

class Note
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :part, inverse_of: :note
end

class Attachment
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true, touch: true
end
```

When I add attachments to a note, I do it via the part

```
def update
  @part = current_user.parts.find params[:id]
  @part.note.update note_params
  …
end
```

What I find strange is the following:

```
def update
  @part = current_user.parts.find params[:id]
  @part.note.update note_params
  @part.note.attachments.any? # => false
  @part.note.attachments.any? # => true
end
```

Why does the first call return false? Since I need this in my view, I'm left with calling @part.note.reload, but I can't understand what is going on.

Thanks

Comment: ``inverse_of: :section`` should be ``inverse_of: :part``

Comment: It was a typo, not the actual source of the issue, the original code doesn't have that typo.

Comment: Seems the cached associations aren't updated. Does `@part.note(true).attachments.any?` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Associations are cached for performance reasons. Use `association(true)` to bypass the cache and force Rails to refetch the current state after you have done something to change it:

```
@part.note(true).attachments.any?
```

See [Association Basic: Controlling Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching).

Comment: Thanks, I had totally forgotten about this.